# DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query

Tags: sql-server, solr, dataimporthandler

I have tried to search for my specific problem but have not found solution. I have also read the wiki on the DIH and seem to have everything set up right but my Query still fails. Thank you for your help

I am running Solr 3.1 with Tomcat 6.0 
Windows server 2003 r2 and SQL 2008

I have the sqljdbc4.jar sitting in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\lib

My solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="config">db-data-config.xml</str>  
  </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

My db-data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"      url="://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=KnowledgeBase_DM" user="user" password="password" /> 
<document>
<entity name="Titles" query="SELECT mrID, mrTitle from KnowledgeBase_DM.dbo.AskMe_Data">
<field column="mrID" name="id" />  
<field column="mrTitle" name="title" />  
<entity name="Desc" query="select meDescription from KnowledgeBase_DM.dbo.AskMe_Data">
<field column="meDescription" name="description" />  
</entity>
</entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

Contents of the log:

```
Jan 25, 2012 2:17:37 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler processConfiguration
 INFO: Processing configuration from solrconfig.xml: {config=db-data-config.xml}
 Jan 25, 2012 2:17:37 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter loadDataConfig
 INFO: Data Configuration loaded successfully 
Jan 25, 2012 2:17:37 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter doFullImport
 INFO: Starting Full Import 
Jan 25, 2012 2:17:37 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter readIndexerProperties
 **WARNING: Unable to read: dataimport.properties**
Jan 25, 2012 2:17:37 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1 call
 INFO: Creating a connection for entity Titles with URL: ://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=KnowledgeBase_DM
 Jan 25, 2012 2:17:37 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1 call
 INFO: Time taken for getConnection(): 0 
Jan 25, 2012 2:17:37 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log 
**SEVERE: Exception while processing: Titles document : SolrInputDocument[{}]:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT mrID, mrTitle from KnowledgeBase_DM.dbo.AskMe_Data Processing Document # 1**
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:72)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:253)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:210)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DebugLogger$2.getData(DebugLogger.java:188)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:238)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:591)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:267)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:186)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:353)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:411)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.handleRequestBody(DataImportHandler.java:205)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
         at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1360) 
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
         at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
         at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:241)
         ... 28 more 

Jan 25, 2012 2:17:37 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log 
**SEVERE: Full Import failed:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT mrID, mrTitle from KnowledgeBase_DM.dbo.AskMe_Data Processing Document # 1**
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:72)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:253)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:210)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DebugLogger$2.getData(DebugLogger.java:188)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:238)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:591)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:267)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:186)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:353)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:411)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.handleRequestBody(DataImportHandler.java:205)
         at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
         at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1360) 
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
         at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
         at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:241)
         ... 28 more 

Jan 25, 2012 2:17:37 PM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 rollback 
INFO: start rollback 
Jan 25, 2012 2:17:37 PM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 rollback 
INFO: end_rollback 
Jan 25, 2012 2:17:37 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute 
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/select params={start=0&dataConfig=<dataConfig>%0d%0a%09<dataSource+driver%3D"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"+url%3D"://localhost:1433;DatabaseName%3DKnowledgeBase_DM"+user%3D"user"+password%3D"password"+/>%0d%0a%09<document>%0d%0a%09%09<entity+dataSource%3D"ds1"+name%3D"Titles"+query%3D"SELECT+mrID,+mrTitle+from+KnowledgeBase_DM.dbo.AskMe_Data">%0d%0a%09%09%09<field+column%3D"mrID"+name%3D"id"+/>%0d%0a%09%09%09<field+column%3D"mrTitle"+name%3D"title"+/>%0d%0a%09%09%09<entity+name%3D"Desc"+query%3D"select+meDescription+from+KnowledgeBase_DM.dbo.AskMe_Data">%0d%0a%09%09%09%09<field+column%3D"meDescription"+name%3D"description"+/>%0d%0a%09%09%09</entity>%0d%0a%09%09</entity>%0d%0a%09</document>%0d%0a</dataConfig>&verbose=on&command=full-import&debug=on&qt=/dataimport&rows=10} status=0 QTime=10
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot to describe the protocol you want to use to connect to your database.
For MSSQL it is

```
url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=KnowledgeBase_DM"
```

I'm pretty sure you do not need to restate tue database name in you query since you have selected it in you url. Wich makes the query to:

```
 query="SELECT mrID, mrTitle from dbo.AskMe_Data"
```

I have never worked wit MSSQL so i do not know if you should use dbo.AskMe_Data or just, like I always use it, AskMe_Data

I think this code should fix the problem:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource  type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=KnowledgeBase_DM" user="user" password="password" /> 
    <document>
        <entity name="Titles" query="SELECT mrID, mrTitle from dbo.AskMe_Data">
            <field column="mrID" name="id" />  
            <field column="mrTitle" name="title" />  
            <entity name="Desc" query="select meDescription from dbo.AskMe_Data">
                <field column="meDescription" name="description" />  
            </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Comment: daanTracebuzz,  
I made those changes but I am still getting the same errors I think it still has more to do with **WARNING: Unable to read: dataimport.properties** I don’t think it’s even getting to the actual sql execution part yet. There are servile tutorials on this and I have followed a few but usually end up with the same result.

Comment: Well a 'WARNING' in a stacktrace is never the point where it went completely wrong, it went wrong where it tried to execute the query. There it says 'SERVERE' and that is the real error..

Comment: I see that we still missed the type declaration in the dataSource, ill add it

Answer (score -1):

The sqljdbc4.jar should be placed in another directory

If this is the place for you config files

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\solr\conf\solrconfig.xml
```

Then the sqljdbc4.jar should be placed here:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\solr\lib\sqljdbc4.jar
```

Comment: It can also help to start again with a completely empty solr and rebuild the whole thing.. Solr can be a bit moody