# Exception when running full import in solr

Tags: solr

I'm trying to run simple database import in SOLR. I have came quite a way. No the problem is when i run

```
http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/db/dataimport?command=full-import.
```

I get that error:

```
Exception while processing: id document : SolrInputDocument[]:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: select definer from event Processing Document # 1
```

in my solrconfig.xml i have:

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

and in data-config.xml i have:

```
 <dataConfig>

 <dataSource name="mysql" 
driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mysql"
user="testuser" password="testpass" 
batchSize="-1" /> 
   <document>
     <entity name="id" 
      query="select definer from event">
        <field column="definer" name="title"/>
      </entity>
   </document>
 </dataConfig>
```

In my log file i see that:

```
 SEVERE: Exception while processing: id document : SolrInputDocument[]:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: select definer from event Processing Document # 1
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:71)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:253)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:210)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:38)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:243)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:465)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:404)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:319)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:227)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:422)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:487)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:468)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'testuser'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:925)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1704)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1250)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2483)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2516)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2301)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:161)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:127)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:366)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:38)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:240)
... 12 more
```

I tried many things from here:

[DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011480/dataimporthandlerexception-unable-to-execute-query)

Comment: Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'testuser'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
Does the user have proper rights defined ?

Comment: wow, i needed to set user to localhost from any and now it works thanks!